# What is the best online bus ticket booking options to travel from Chennai to Bangalore?

Tags: tickets, bookings, buses

I am seeing a lot of options for booking ticket for travelling between Chennai to Bangalore (India). Could someone recommend the best option considering cost and service?

Comment: Many good questions generate some degree of opinion based on expert experience, but answers to this question will tend to be almost entirely based on opinions, rather than facts, references, or specific expertise.